# Read lines at different indexes

Tags: c#, indexing, readlines

Here is some code i put together to search for numbers in a text file. It work's great for what i'm trying to do. right now it finds 7 locations and i need to read the lines at the 7 different indexes. what might be the best way to start this. Thanks, this is in C#.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "";

        using (OpenFileDialog dlgOpen = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            //long count = 0; string line;
            //bool start = false;
            //string line;
            List<String> LinesFound = new List<string>();
            // Available file extensions 
            dlgOpen.Filter = "All files(*.*)|*.*";
            // Initial directory 
            dlgOpen.InitialDirectory = "C://bin";
            // OpenFileDialog title 
            dlgOpen.Title = "Load";
            // Show OpenFileDialog box 
            if (dlgOpen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                textBox1.Text = dlgOpen.FileName;

            {
                string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(dlgOpen.FileName);
                Regex reg = new Regex("333333");
                Match sat = reg.Match(str);
                while (sat.Success)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += (sat.Index + "                    "); //shows index where 333333 is
                    sat = reg.Match(str, sat.Index + sat.Length);
                      {

                              {


                              }
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it'd be helpful if you mentioned what language this is. I'm guessing C# or perhaps ASP of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReadAllLines instead of ReadAllText, and match each line one by one, use a int[] variable to store all your matching line index.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/files/file.txt");

            Regex reg = new Regex("333333");
            string str;
            for(int i =1; i<lines.Length;i++)
            {
                str = lines[i];
                Match sat = reg.Match(str);
                if (sat.Success)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += (i + 1 +"                    "); //shows index where 333333 is

                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, i would like to take the index's i have with this and print each line in there own richTextBox.

Comment: sorry, changing ReadAllText to ReadAllLines did not give the desired output.

Comment: @user1926235, update the answer with code. I test with local file and it works.

Comment: You can use another string[] to store line content every time it matches your regex. You don't have to read it another time

Comment: also i noticed a little search hack. when adding numbers to search for in a text and don't want to get all the other variable from different size numbers. you can copy the number from a hex reader with 01 at the beginning and it will only find what you want when you copy and paste to your code. example: 01 33 33 33 33 33 33  then select to copy 333333.

Comment: i think there are difference between my code and yours. my code produces indexes of 173741,176813,177837,1563729,1563750. yours only produces 731 and 10947. in a hex reader if i go to dec 173741 it shows 333333. yours does not.